# Kinetics JS "Click" or simple "Touch" event for Mobile device

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js

I want to handle mobile touch event on group for ios & android.

I am binding event such as following

```
group.on('touchstart', function (evt) {

    $('#onpopMenu').popup("open", { x: leftPosition, y: topPosition });

});
```

I tried 'touchend', 'touchstart' and 'tap'

Got partial success in "Tap" but in that case, shape is draggable so tap event is not properly fire because object will move from it's place.

but if shape is not draggable then it will work fine.

I tried 'touchend' and 'touchstart' event also but popup menu is close after event fire in iOs and android as I am opening Jquery Mobile Popup by Touching group!

The popup menu will only open for 2-3 seconds when the touchstart event fired.

Anyone faced the same problem with kinetic JS Mobile events? How to handle only "Click" or "Touch" event with it.

I checked this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-mobile-events/ for reference but had no luck!

I am developing application with Phonegap + JQM + Kinetics JS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, I recommend updating to the latest KineticJS version if at all possible for your project.

Comment: I tired the new version but it is still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your application is running inside a webview. This is why you've got these 2/3 seconds of delay on touch/click event.
This is why in all my PhoneGap dev, I use Fastclick.js. FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers. The aim is to make your application feel less laggy and more responsive while avoiding any interference with your current logic.
You can find it here https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.
It's easy to use (if you're using jQuery) :

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='/path/to/fastclick.js'></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This can work with HTML and Jquery Mobile UI but I want to handle the Click or Touch event on HTML5 KineticsJS Canvas. Question is regarding how you handle touch or click event in KinjeticsJS not in Jquery Mobile. And I am already using FastClick with JQM from very first version of it!

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/EaeUd/) for you to test out the click/touch events.

From what I understand, you have a `Kinetic.Group` node that is `draggable` but you want to open up a **popup** using jquery mobile.

You are right that when you **drag** an object, the **tap** event does not fire. But you said otherwise the **tap** event works fine if the shape is not draggable. This leads me to believe:

1. You want a popup on "tap"
2. You want a popup on "dragend"

If so, all you need is to use both events like this:

```
group.on('tap dragend', function (evt) {
  $('#onpopMenu').popup("open", { x: leftPosition, y: topPosition });
});
```

Please let me know if my assumptions are wrong, and I can work with you to get the right solution. I am guessing when you want to popup, so if you let me know exactly when you want a popup to occur that will help a lot.

You might want to also look into using **`evt.cancelBubble = true;`** http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-cancel-event-bubble-propagation-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I tried your above code but it is not working when shape or group is dragable. for "dragend" I need to drag group but I only want to click on group!